# Getting permission denied lmtp/sieve error

Tags: postfix, dovecot, sieve

I set up sieve for the first time on a Debian machine running postfix/dovecot/lmtp. It works, however I want to clear up an error I've been getting:

`lmtp(joeblow)<17980><GG5KL91cf188RgAAajKqBA>: Error: sieve: binary save: failed to create temporary file: open(/var/lib/dovecot/sieve/default.svbin.) failed: Permission denied (euid=1008(joeblow) egid=1009(joeblow) missing +w perm: /var/lib/dovecot/sieve, dir owned by 0:0 mode=0755)`

`lmtp(joeblow)<17980><GG5KL91cf188RgAAajKqBA>: Error: sieve: The LDA Sieve plugin does not have permission to save global Sieve script binaries; global Sieve scripts like '/var/lib/dovecot/sieve/default.sieve' need to be pre-compiled using the sievec tool`

AFAICT, it's coming in when an email is received. I'm not entirely sure I need the lda if I have lmtp but I really don't know what I'm doing so not sure what to do at all. It took me a while to figure this configuration out and I did it several days ago.

My 90-sieve.conf file:

```
plugin {
  sieve = file:~/sieve;active=~/.dovecot.sieve
  sieve_default = /var/lib/dovecot/sieve/default.sieve
  sieve_default_name = Defaults
  sieve_global = /var/lib/dovecot/sieve
  sieve_user_log = ~/.dovecot.sieve.log
}
```

```
# 2.3.4.1 (f79e8e7e4): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.5.4 ()
# OS: Linux 4.19.0-11-cloud-amd64 x86_64 Debian 10.6
auth_debug = yes
auth_debug_passwords = yes
auth_mechanisms = plain login
auth_username_format = %Ln
auth_verbose = yes
mail_debug = yes
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
mail_privileged_group = mail
managesieve_notify_capability = mailto
managesieve_sieve_capability = fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date index ihave duplicate mime foreverypart extracttext
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
plugin {
  sieve = file:~/sieve;active=~/.dovecot.sieve
  sieve_default = /var/lib/dovecot/sieve/default.sieve
  sieve_default_name = Defaults
  sieve_global = /var/lib/dovecot/sieve
  sieve_user_log = ~/.dovecot.sieve.log
}
protocols = " imap lmtp sieve pop3 sieve"
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    mode = 0666
  }
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 143
  }
  inet_listener imaps {
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
  }
  service_count = 1
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0600
    user = postfix
  }
}
service managesieve-login {
  inet_listener sieve {
    port = 4190
  }
  process_min_avail = 1
}
service pop3-login {
  inet_listener pop3s {
    port = 995
    ssl = yes
  }
}
service pop3 {
  process_limit = 1024
}
service submission {
  process_limit = 1024
}
ssl_cert = </opt/bitnami/letsencrypt/certificates/email.example.org.crt
ssl_client_ca_dir = /etc/ssl/certs
ssl_dh = # hidden, use -P to show it
ssl_key = # hidden, use -P to show it
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
protocol lmtp {
  mail_plugins = " sieve"
}
protocol lda {
  mail_plugins = " sieve"
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets unpack this error message

> lmtp(joeblow)<17980>:

This is the LMTP service talking to you

> error: sieve: The LDA Sieve plugin does not have permission to save global Sieve script binaries;

You are applying some sieve filtering globally, and the LMTP service (more specifically, the delivery part, hence the `LDA` term) is configured to call sieve filtering, which in turn is currently unable to write binary caches of the global scripts.

> global Sieve scripts like '/var/lib/dovecot/sieve/default.sieve' need to be pre-compiled using the sievec tool

This is precisely what you can do to resolve this - compile your file:

```
sievec /var/lib/dovecot/sieve/default.sieve
```

That will create a binary cache of that file in `/var/lib/dovecot/sieve/default.svbin` that can be used by the sieve plugin.

*Dovecot could have called this automatically, but your file permissions prohibit it (rightfully so in your setup, as authentication via PAM means users login as themselves, as indicated in the `euid=` hint above). Hence just have to call `sievec` manually.*

Comment: I had already run sievec manually and the default.svbin file already exists. I want those sieve rules to be automatically applied to the user's incoming email.

Comment: I think probably what I should be doing is setting up a default sieve file in the user's directory that is copied over from /etc/skel.

Comment: Interestingly, in my case, I got that cryptic message too but was baffled at _why_ `sievec` had to be run again on a file that allegedly had been compiled quite a while ago. As it turns out, the `xxx.sieve` file that was the source of complaints was _corrupted_ beyond repair — I must have overwritten it by mistake. It turns out that Dovecot noticed that, tried to re-compile the file, but failed due to the read-only filesystem restrictions... So neither the filesystem, nor Dovecot, nor `sievec`, nor even `systemd` were to blame — just me! 